# How to make QFileSystemModel work with a ListView

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am unable to make the QFileSystemModel go along with the ListView. All the examples and documentation that I found would use QFileSystemModel with the TreeView (which works fine), but this is not what I need.

I do not want to use FolderListModel QML type either because I want to add extra roles to my model later and edit/delete files and folders from the application.

I used DelegateModel to be able to set an other root index. For some reason, my files are correctly displayed for a fraction of a second and then the view jumps to the root of my filesystem. I'm not sure what happens, maybe the indexes are invalidated somehow.

Below is a sample of my code:

main.cpp

```
    QFileSystemModel *fsm = new QFileSystemModel(&engine);
    fsm->setRootPath(QDir::homePath());
    fsm->setResolveSymlinks(true);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("displayFileSystemModel", fsm);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("rootPathIndex", fsm->index(fsm->rootPath()));
```

fsview.qml

```
ListView {
    width: 300
    height: 400

    model: DelegateModel {
        model: displayFileSystemModel
        rootIndex: rootPathIndex

        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 200; height: 25
            Text {
                text: model.filePath
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log(text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

So, apparently QFileSystemModel uses a separate thread to populate itself and shoots a directoryLoaded signal once the the thread has finished to load the path.

I tried connecting my view to only set the root index once the path has been properly loaded by adding the following code to my listview

```
    Connections {
        target: displayFileSystemModel
        function onDirectoryLoaded(path) { delegatemodel.rootIndex = rootPathIndex }
    }
```

However, this does not solve the problem. <s>A dirty workaround was to set a timer to try set the rootIndex after a period of time.</s>

```
    Timer {
        interval: 100
        running: true
        onTriggered: delegatemodel.rootIndex = examPathIndex
    }
```

And this "solves" the problem but of course is far from a satisfactory solution. Any idea?

**UPDATE 2**

Turns out every time the model is updated (and the directoryLoaded signal is triggered), the view resets. Even trying to reassign the rootIndex every time new data is loaded doesn't work.

Comment: What happens if you remove that `rootIndex` line? I'm just looking at the example [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html#rootIndex-prop) and they don't set `rootIndex` until you click on a folder.

Comment: @JarMan If I remove the rootIndex, the default path is the root of the system. I want to display a specific folder and its subfolders in my application. Furthermore, when I follow the example that you linked, the problem persists: I can click on the folder to access its subfolder but every few seconds, the displayed path jumps back to the root of my system again.